# Combine txt files under 2 folders with subfolders

Tags: java, file

I have two directories with identical folder tree structure and file names. These are the data of current week and last week. I want to combine (append the new data to the old ones) each pair of them (name to name) into and save it under another directory with the original file tree structure.

How do I do it in Java? Please help.
What is the best way to read and write a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would use a recursive approach, iterating over the current week's structure.  For each file found, locate the corresponding files in last week's structure and append it to the current week's file.  If the structures are not guaranteed to be identical, you might also need to recurse over last week's files to pick up anything that does not exist in this week's directory tree.

As for the actual *Java* part of the question, *i.e.* the implementation of those operations, the following may be helpful:

[java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html)

[java.io.FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html)

[java.io.FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html)

[Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)